# Allow remote access to Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, connectivity, listener

After finishing the installation of Oracle 12c on Centos 7, now I try to allow access on my PC (via SQL Developer) to the server. The problem is that when I do:

```
lsnrctl status
```

I get this error:

```
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

So, I try to start the listener with:

```
lsnrctl start
```

And I get this error:

```
TNS-01198: Listener failed to initialize valid node list
 NL-07007: internal error
  NL-00408: cannot find or read value
   NL-00408: cannot find or read value
    NL-00408: cannot find or read value
```

To finish I go to this website:
[TNS-01198: Listener failed to initialize valid node list post upgrade from 11g to 12c](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ORA/TNS-01198%3A+Listener+failed+to+initialize+valid+node+list+post+upgrade+from+11g+to+12c)

Then I added, as he tell the following line on the `listener.ora` file:

```
VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_<LISTENER_SERVICENAME> = OFF
```

but nothing change.

To finish, this is my `listener.ora` file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_<LISTENER_SID> = OFF


LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =  ns330926.ip-37-187-120.eu)(PORT = 1521))

      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

I added my hostname in the `/etc/hosts` file.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: CentOS is not a certified OS for running an Oracle database, so that might be the problem. Do the alert logs of the listener show anything?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by adding this correct line on the `listener.ora` file:

```
VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER=OFF
```

now the listener is starting.